# Show that if $z$ is a complex number such that $z^5$ + 5$z^2$ + 7 = 0, then |$z$| > 1.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, complex-numbers, proof-explanation

How do I show that if $z$ is a complex number such that $z^5$ + 5$z^2$ + 7 = 0, then |$z$| > 1.

I thought maybe try by contradiction i.e letting |$z$| $\leq$ 1.

But then I ended up getting |$z^5$ + 5$z^2$ + 7| $\leq$ 13, which doesn't help my case.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I'd first rewrite your equality:
$$
-7=z^5+5z^2.
$$
Now take absolute values, and use the triangle inequality:
$$
7\le |z|^5+5|z|^2.
$$
Now argue by contradiction: if $|z|\le 1$, then the right hand side can be bounded by
$$
7\le 1^5+5\cdot 1^2=6,
$$
which is clearly impossible.

Answer (score 1):

If $|z|\leq 1$ then $|z^{5}+5z^{2}+7| \geq 7-|z^{5}+5z^{2}|\geq 7-1-5=1$ so $z^{5}+5z^{2}+7$ cannot be $0$. [I have used the inequality $|a+b| \geq |a|-|b|$ which is true for all $a,b \in \mathbb C]$.